# Does slicing an array using Index/Range create a copy of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, c#-8.0

With C# 8.0 seeing the introduction of the structs `Index` and `Range` we can now easily get a slice of an array doing something like

```cs
string[] baseArray = {"a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

var arr = baseArray[1..^2];
```

Does slicing an array like this copy the array? Or does it do it without copying like `ArraySegment<T>`?

Comment: Your tests aren't really valid. All you're doing it creating the structures, not using them. For example, the Linq version just returns an `IEnumerable` but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @DavidG alright, thanks for pointing that out. Removed my test case. However the original question still stands wether or not it copies the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it yourself :

```cs
string[] baseArray = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
var arr = baseArray[1..^2];
Debug.WriteLine(arr[0]);
Debug.WriteLine(baseArray[1]);
arr[0] = "hello";
Debug.WriteLine(arr[0]);
Debug.WriteLine(baseArray[1]);
```

**Output**

```
b
b
hello
b
```

We can conclude that the **string** array is copied.

However, if we are using an array of objects :

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

Foo[] baseArray =
{
    new Foo { Bar = "a" },
    new Foo { Bar = "b" },
    new Foo { Bar = "c" },
    new Foo { Bar = "d" },
    new Foo { Bar = "e" },
    new Foo { Bar = "f" }
};

var arr = baseArray[1..^2];
Debug.WriteLine(arr[0].Bar);
Debug.WriteLine(baseArray[1].Bar);
arr[0].Bar = "hello";
Debug.WriteLine(arr[0].Bar);
Debug.WriteLine(baseArray[1].Bar);

arr[0] = new Foo { Bar = "World" };
Debug.WriteLine(arr[0].Bar);
Debug.WriteLine(baseArray[1].Bar);
```

This outputs

```
b
b
hello
hello
World
hello
```

Objects in the array aren't copied but referenced.

Setting another object in an array won't affect the other one.